# plotly js: location and length of color scale in heatmap

Tags: javascript, plotly

Using plotly.js, you can make a heatmap, and the heatmap comes with a color scale on the right side, as do some of the 3d charts.

Here is an **[example in codepen](http://codepen.io/plotly/pen/xGeEXo?editors=1010)**.

[image]

```
Plotly.d3.json('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/plotly/datasets/master/custom_heatmap_colorscale.json', function(figure) {
var data = [{
    z: figure.z,
    colorscale: 'Jet',
    type: 'heatmap'
  }
];
var layout = {title: 'Jet'};
Plotly.newPlot('myDiv', data, layout);
});
```

I am struggling to see if the api allows the color scale **location** and **length** to be modified. Does plotly.js allow manipulation of these attributes, and do you have an example of this for a heatmap and/or 3d graph?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can set the [position](https://plot.ly/javascript/reference/#heatmap-colorbar-x) and [length](https://plot.ly/javascript/reference/#heatmap-colorbar-len) of the `colorbar` by adding the following line to your `data`:

```
colorbar: {x: -.5, len: 0.5}
```

---

Below is a snippet with a colorbar pushed to the left and half the regular size.

```js
Plotly.d3.json('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/plotly/datasets/master/custom_heatmap_colorscale.json', function(figure) {
var data = [{
    z: figure.z,
    colorscale: 'Jet',
    type: 'heatmap',
    colorbar: {x: -.5, len: 0.5}
  }
];
var layout = {title: 'Jet'};
Plotly.newPlot('myDiv', data, layout);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.plot.ly/plotly-latest.min.js"></script>
  <div id="myDiv" style="width: 480px; height: 400px;"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Adding this answer to show more tweaks you can do on `Plotly colorbar`

```
 var plotData8kW = [{
           z: data8kW,
            hoverinfo:"z",
            colorbar:{
                //  len: 0.35, //Change size of bar
                title: 'Speed(RPM)<br\><br\>', //set title
                titleside:'top', //set postion
               //tickvals:[0,50,100],
                titlefont: {color: 'blue'} //title font color
              },
             type: 'heatmap',
             colorscale: enhancedScale,
             },
     ];
```